# YouTube Data API does not return live

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-data-api

I have been using api for quite some time to get a list of live broadcasts by channel id

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?eventType=live&part=id&channelId=UCz7ttPTNO_S1PS9rNsCt_iA&type=video&key={MY_KEY}
```

Everything worked fine, but today YouTube started returning 0 in the items field

```
"kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
"etag": "j56oEfFnMdSM5vrZZHR792eHM3Y",
"regionCode": "UA",
"pageInfo": {
"totalResults": 0,
"resultsPerPage": 0
},
"items": [],
}
```

Although the broadcasts are on, I tried it for other channels, the result is the same. What can be wrong?

Comment: I recommend to follow closely [this issue report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187740626) from Google's issue tracker site.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the problem is fixed